# ActionListener Issue: Program to see if a number is prime or not? (Java GUI)

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

so my problem with this code is in the ActionListner I believe. When running the program I input a number and nothing happens. The only number that the program will run properly is when I input the number 2. I'm obviously doing something wrong in the for loop but I haven't been able to figure it out yet.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Prime implements ActionListener {
    JFrame framePrime;

    JPanel panelPrime;

    JTextField primeTestField;

    JLabel stringPrimelLabel, enterNumLabel, trueFalseLabel;

    // Constructor
    public Prime() {
        // Create the frame and container.
        framePrime = new JFrame("Prime or Not?");
        panelPrime = new JPanel();
        panelPrime.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));


    // Add the widgets.
    addWidgets();

    // Add the panel to the frame.
    framePrime.getContentPane().add(panelPrime, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // Exit when the window is closed.
    framePrime.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // Show the converter.
    framePrime.pack();
    framePrime.setVisible(true);
    }

    // Create and add the widgets for converter.
    private void addWidgets() {

        // Create widgets.
        primeTestField = new JTextField();
        primeTestField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        enterNumLabel = new JLabel("Enter a number:            ",          
                                             SwingConstants.LEFT);
        stringPrimelLabel = new JLabel("Is it Prime?:  ", 
                                             SwingConstants.LEFT);
        trueFalseLabel = new JLabel("Let's Find Out!",
                                           SwingConstants.CENTER);

        // Listen to events from Convert textfield.
        primeTestField.addActionListener(this);

        // Add widgets to container.
        panelPrime.add(enterNumLabel);
        panelPrime.add(primeTestField);
        panelPrime.add(stringPrimelLabel);
        panelPrime.add(trueFalseLabel);

        panelPrime.setBackground(Color.red);
    }

    // Implementation of ActionListener interface.
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        int n = Integer.parseInt(primeTestField.getText());

        if (n == 2) {
            trueFalseLabel.setText("Yes");
        }
        else {
             for (int i = 2; 2*i < n; i++) {
                if(n % i == 0){
                     trueFalseLabel.setText("No");
                }
                else {
                     trueFalseLabel.setText("Yes");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Prime converter = new Prime();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you press the [enter] key (while the primeTestField had focus)?

Comment: Whery strange and wrong method of determination prime number

Comment: As above, this is wrong way to go about this, but from your code, I think your problem is this line:
`for (int i = 2; 2*i < n; i++) {`. If you input 3, 2*i (4) is never < 3, so your loop doesn't proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActionListener` for JTextField is triggered when you press enter in the text field.

**Edit:** If you want to do the prime check whenever the value is changed in the text field. As suggested by @MadProgrammer, you can add a `DocumentListener` to the document of the text field and implement the `insertUpdate` (called when you add a character) and `removeUpdate` (called when you remove a character) methods.

```
primeTestField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
            check();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            check();
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        }
    });
```

(PS: I corrected and refactored your prime check logic into a method so that it is correct & reusable)

```
private void check() {
    int n;
    try {
        System.out.println(primeTestField.getText());
        n = Integer.parseInt(primeTestField.getText());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return;
    }
    if (n == 2) {
        trueFalseLabel.setText("Yes");
    } else {
        boolean isPrime = true;
        for (int i = 2; 2 * i < n; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime) {
            trueFalseLabel.setText("Yes");
        } else {
            trueFalseLabel.setText("No");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I suggest you to add a keyListener to the text field and override the keyReleased method:"* - I **strongly** suggest you don't (and don't recommend the use of `KeyListener `generally in Swing, but especially not for text components), if you "really" wanted to know when the field is updated, use a `DocumentListener` instead (see [Listening for Changes on a Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners)), but a button would be a simpler solution all round.

Comment: So, I'll give you a +1 for the first sentence and a -1 for the `KeyListener`

Comment: Thank you guys for the help, I was able to make the program using a button but also still did the textfield way so I can learn more about DocumentListner.